# How to Use ifContain Dynamically?

Tags: json, report, odt

Hi guys I'm using **carbone.io** for report binding, I've been struck from past few days. Actually For text replacement I'm Using :ifContain for example : {d.j1.INITIATOR.afterTypeACleaning3.18WipeThePartsWith70Ipa:ifContain(satisfactory✔, ✓):ifContain(no,X)} Here I'm replacing text with ✓ if it exists satisfactory✔ . Like the way now I had a requirement that if the text contains satisfactory✔ then I should map another Key else remain same.This is what I'm Trying {d.j1.INITIATOR.ensureThatStatusLabelIsUpdatedAsToBeCleaned:ifContain(S,({d.j1.USER[key="ensureThatStatusLabelIsUpdatedAsToBeCleaned"].commitedUser}))} .Where I'm doing wrong?Please throw some light. Does carbone support this kind of thing?

Answer (score 1):

Your use case is actually too complex for Carbone JS, it's not possible to render dynamically markers into formatters.
The best practice is to compute the JSON data by your own before calling Carbone.

If you need more informations about ifContain formatter, check the [Carbone documentation](https://carbone.io/documentation.html#ifcontain-value-messageiftrue-continueonsuccess-) or if you need help, post an issue on the [Carbone Github](https://github.com/Ideolys/carbone/issues).